# Drupal Commerce: How to select the product Variation by it's own thumbnail?

Tags: commerce

Want to select the product variation by it's own thumbnail instead it's color. 
The module Fancy Attribute only shows separate images or colors, but not the thumb from the product variation it self.

Example: 
http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00WGEQ7OQ